# MacBook Pro 3.1 german keyboard with Ubuntu 12.4 (@ and € keys)

Tags: macbook-pro

How can I with Ubuntu 12.4 type characters like @ or € with my MacBook Pro 3.1 german keyboard?

Answer (score 2):

To view the present keyboard layout we open the gnome-control-center (click the cogwheel on the upper right to select *"System Settings..."*) and choose the *"Keyboard Layout"* icon in the to row:

[image]

There you can change your present layout (press + for a selection) or view the present  keyboard layout by selecting the little keyboad symbol at the bottom right. This will open a window that shows all characters assigned together with their location:

[image]

Here the <kbd>@</kbd> sign is on the fourth level of key <kbd>1</kbd>, the <kbd>€</kbd> sign is on the third and fourth level of key <kbd>E</kbd>.